# Authentication and authorization ASP.NET Web API from another Web API Application

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization

Hi everyone I have an issue, I have one Asp.NET Web.API application with User management functionality from example Create User manage User Permissions ect, and now I have developed another Web.API application and I need to implement authentication and authorization via first application users credentials. What is the best approach or solution to achieve this goal?  Note that in first app I changed the classic Role base Authorization into Permission based.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: In case possible separate authentication as a separate service and implement token based authentication.

Comment: Thanks for answer what type of service do you mean?

Comment: Another rest api service which implements token based authentication.

Comment: Do you have any example to point me?

Comment: There are several ways you can achieve token based authentication. My preference is to use OAuth using ASP.net identity server. https://github.com/IdentityServer

Answer (score 1):

> I have developed another Web.API application and I need to implement
>   authentication and authorization via first application users
>   credentials.

There are a lot of ways to implement the solution. One way is use to ***token-based authentication*** using ***[Identity Server](https://github.com/IdentityServer)***.

You could test [my sample code at GitHub](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/IdentityExample).

Please note that it uses InMemory Identity Database with [hard-coded username and password](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/IdentityExample/blob/master/src/IdentityServer/Startup.cs#L69) for testing. You could replace with real Identity Database easily.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue so I moved all of my authentication and authorization into an IHTTP Module. This allowed me to set the applications module in IIS 7.0.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx